# How to get constexpr from iterating variable?

Tags: c++, arduino, constexpr

I am trying to use a `for` loop that makes a function call requiring a constant expression:

```cpp
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    func(variable_that_is_constexpr)
}
```

How do I turn `x` into a constant expression?

The following didn't work, as it reports an error:

```cpp
constexpr int toConstExpr(int x){
    return x;
}
constexpr y = toConstExpr(z);
```

> the value of 'z' is not usable in a constant expression

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to do the above so I can loop through constant expressions for a function as demonstrated below

```
constexpr int pins[2] = {1, 2};
for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++){
    func(pins[x]);
}
```

> the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression

**EDIT TWO:**

To give the exact example of what I'm trying to do. I have pin numbers in an array. I want to declare ledstrips using these pin numbers. The function to declare the led strips requires that the pins be constant expressions. I want to do the following:

```
constexpr int pins[] = {1, 2};
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++}{
      FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, pins[x], GRB>(leds[x], 5).setCorrection( TypicalLEDStrip );
}
```

> the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression

**EDIT THREE**

Is there a pretty way that doesn't require duplicating the same line numerous times to do this, where the number I'm changing has to be a constant?

```
FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, 3, GRB>(leds[0], 5).setCorrection( TypicalLEDStrip );
FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, 4, GRB>(leds[1], 5).setCorrection( TypicalLEDStrip );
FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, 5, GRB>(leds[2], 5).setCorrection( TypicalLEDStrip );
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression

Comment: Your question is unclear. E.g. the fact that you want to use a counter variable from a loop in a way which is explicitly for constant expressions only. I get an impression of "I want to use a non-flying bird, e.g. a penguin, as a flying mail carrier." As a whole, I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem So please take a logical step back and explain what you actually want to achieve this way.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have an array of constants. I am trying to plug each one into a function. I can't use a simple for loop though because the variable iterated in the for loop won't be a constant expression. I guess my question is more accurately described as how to loop through constant expressions using a constant expression index so the whole expression is a constant expression.

Comment: Please explain by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: @Yunnosch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dfWzp7rYR4

Comment: @user4581301 Yes I know. I saw that video before my minds eye while typing...

Comment: Sorry, but for me "loop through..." and "const expression" are two inherently contradicting ideas. Please try the XY problem link. Or to put it differently. Try to let go of the "use non-const as const" idea. Assume that the answer is a categorical "impossible" and you really are convinced of it. What is it you then want help with?

Comment: @Yunnosch I provided exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: Yes what you are trying to do. But could you explain about what you want to achieve by doing that? Go one step in the direction of more-abstract. "I want to use an egg to hammer that nail into hard wood." Could you agree that a recommendation which other, more suitable tool to use would also be helpful in that situation? Like "I want to hammer that nail into hard wood. What tool could I use for that?" Or to go with my previous example: "Try carrier pigeons instead of penguins." would be a helpful answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: I want to be able to declare a number of led strips. I'd rather not copy and paste the line to do so numerous times, because then I will need to manually change all the values if I want to change a different parameter. Instead I'd like to use a for loop to conveniently declare them all.

Comment: Ah, much better. Now show an example of the tedious but working code, which you want to make more elegant, more maintainable, more readable (at least that is what I now understand you actually want to do).

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with std::integer_sequence, which is a sequence of integers that can be traversed at compile-time.

```
#include <utility>

consteval void func(int i) {}

template<typename T, T... ints>
void call_func(std::integer_sequence<T, ints...> int_seq)
{
    (func(ints),...);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto is = std::make_index_sequence<10>();
    call_func(is);
}
```

Example adapted from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

Comment: In case it's not obvious to OP, they'll need to replace `func(ints)` with `FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, pins[ints], GRB>(leds[ints], 5).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip)`.

Comment: How do I include utility on Arduino? I got `fatal error: utility: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Cammy_the_block You don't. Arduino compiler is crippled. It is not really a C++ compiler. You learn how to write your own  `integer_sequence` (not hard, but no guarantee it will work with Arduino compiler), copy an implementation from elsewhere (e.g. libstdc++, but again no guarantee it will work with Arduino compiler), try to adapt one of the C++ standard library ports for Arduino (there are several), or just write 10 calls to func() by hand, which seems to be the easiest option so far.